# Does my switch update its router table automatically

Tags: networking, ip, ping, router, switching

I have a HP ProCurve switch, I recently added 2 new machines to the network, which I had to assign the IP addresses to manually. Now using these 2 machines I can ping my current machine and other machines on the network, however if I try to ping those 2 machines from my current machine (or others on the network) it does not go through. So my thoughts are that the router table has not updated so that's why I can't ping them from machines that have been on this router. 
(Not too sure, not enough knowledge yet)

At least I think so. My question is does the Router Table update it's information automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your HP Procurve is acting only as a switch, then the Routing Table should not be your problem. A switch does not route IPs, a switch is concerned with routing packets via their layer-2 addresses (MAC addresses). The switch determined which physical port is connected to a device with a MAC address, and when it gets a packet addressed to that MAC address, it sends the packet out that port. The mapping on port to destination mac address is stored in a [CAM table](https://www.packet6.com/cam-table-fundamental-switch-operations/) inside the switch. This is very different from a routing table that maps IP address ranges to physical interfaces.

What is probably happening is that ARP is not resolving. ARP binds layer 3 IPs to layer 2 MACs in a local network. This can be cause for a few reasons. The first thing i would look into is if the switch has VLANs enabled. This makes the switch act like multiple isolated switches. After that you may need to look at your computers ARP tables to make sure they are correct. The `arping` command will be useful.